# external fonts are not loading/working in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, fonts

external fonts are not loading/working in windows phone 8

Xaml Code i tried :

1) TextBlock Text="Hello world" FontFamily="CentraleSans-Light.ttf#CentraleSansLight" />

2) TextBlock Text="Hello world" FontFamily="/WPSL81App;component/CentraleSans-Light.ttf#CentraleSansLight" />

i placed the CentraleSans-Light.ttf file in root folder of the project

please let me know the problem as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

most likely the problem is that, you should set the font's properties **Build Action** to **Resource** and **Copy to Output directory** to **Copy aways** or **Copy if newer**